# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade unity error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

Execution failed for task :launcher:processReleaseResources. > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade    > Android resource linking failed.      C:\Users\Uche-Orji Michael.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\cac0526fac8a06cd07b67df880360aca\jetified-facebook-common-15.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml:32:17-69: AAPT: error: unexpected element < property > found in < manifest>< application>.

```
manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.facebook.common" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="31" />

    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.facebook.katana" />
    </queries>

    <application>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@style/com_facebook_activity_theme" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:node="merge" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="cct.${applicationId}"
                    android:scheme="fbconnect" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I've been stuck with this error for 2 days now, I need help

This is the Android manifest file that's causing the error, I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Can you please check MergedManifest file

Comment: What am I checking for exactly?

Comment: You need to check the mergedManifest file it is with the manifest file. There the errors of manifest file are listed

Comment: I don't know where to find it

Answer (score 0):

as the error shows you an unexpected element  inside the AndroidManifest.xml of the jetified-facebook-common-15.2.0 library.

try to clean the project

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Comment: How do I clean the project?

Comment: ./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleRelease

Comment: Open a Terminal or Command Prompt: Navigate to the root directory of your Android project (where the build.gradle and settings.gradle files are located).

Comment: In android studio -> build -> clean project

Comment: It didn't work.